# Is it possible to call a latex macro at the command line in order to return a string, not create a document?

Tags: macros

I'm curious as to whether there is a way to pass a small amount of LaTeX code to a compiler at the command line and return the string corresponding to the value of a variable or length.

For instance I would like to pass this code

```
\usepackage{calc}
\def\contnt{\tt{I wish I knew how much space was occupied by this string when typeset...}
\settowidth{\contntwdth}{\contnt}
```

and I'd like to indicate that the string output I'm after is the width of the content e.g.

```
\the\contntwdth
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: As TeX's output tends to be in files, the most obvious place to put the string is in the `.log` or a dedicated text file. The latter avoids needing to parse the log: does that sound about right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. We like to avoid greetings and closing lines here. Your (user-)name is already added automatically at the bottom of all your posts. You might want to rename the generic user name you currently have.

Comment: The tool [`texdef`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) written by me does something very similar, i.e. returning the definition of macros and also values, but your example might be already be to complicated. (Also, your use of `\tt` is incorrect and `\tt` is outdated altogether, use `{\ttfamily ..}` or `\texttt{..}` instead.)

Comment: If needed, [the `printlen` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/printlen) can be used to convert to display the length in different units.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`texdef`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) tool written by me can be used to display the definition of macros and the value of dimension and other registers. It also allows to add arbitrary other code before (`-b`) and after the definition/value is printed.

Your example would be (code got refactored):

```
$ texdef -t latex  -p calc -b '\newdimen\mydim \settowidth{\mydim}{\texttt{I wish I knew how much space was occupied by this string when typeset...}}' -v mydim

\the\mydim:
377.9967pt
```

If required a wrapper script could be written which inserts the actual text in the position and removes unwanted lines in the output.

Comment: Why should `calc` be required?

Comment: @egreg: Well, it is indeed not required. I blindly copied it from the original code. I will let it stay as an example how to include packages in `texdef`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple Bash script, say `getdim`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
latex << EOF | sed -n -e '/^\*\*\*\*/s///p'
\documentclass{article}
\nofiles
\begin{document}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{\ttfamily $1}\typeout{***\the\dimen0}
\stop
EOF
```

If you run

```
bash getdim "test of script"
```

you get the following output

```
73.49936pt
```

(Thanks to Marc van Dongen for suggesting an improvement in the usage of `sed`.)

Comment: `latex << EOF | sed -n -e '/^\*\*\*\*/s///p' ....` also does the trick and saves a `grep` and a pipe. The `-n` is for no-print. The `p` forces the printing.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Thanks; this shows how little I know `sed`. :)

Comment: You're being too modest. Most people wouldn't know `sed` at all and the `-n` flag isn't used much.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\immediate\write18` to output the length. The MWE below yields:

> The content width is 377.9967pt.

The same code can be used to evaluate lengths of different strings.
Saving the code below as `GetLength.tex`, and running it from the command line as:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape "\def\contnt{\tt{Here is a different string}}\input{GetLength.tex}"  | grep "content width"
```

yields:

> The content width is 136.49881pt.

### Code:

```
\ifdefined\contnt
\else
    \def\contnt{\texttt{I wish I knew how much space was occupied by this string when typeset...}}
\fi

\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\contntwdth}
\settowidth{\contntwdth}{\contnt}
\begin{document}
    \immediate\write18{echo ""; echo "The content width is \the\contntwdth."}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can pass commands on the commandline without using any auxiliary files.

For example the following just outputs `377.9967pt`  The `| sed -e "1,/loaded/d"` at the end just deletes the startup banner and list of hyphenation patterns, if you don't have `sed` then just omit that bit.

```
$ pdflatex '\batchmode\newlength\contntwdth\def\contnt{\texttt{I wish I knew how much space was occupied by this string when typeset...}}\settowidth{\contntwdth}{\contnt}\scrollmode\typeout{\the\contntwdth}\batchmode\stop' | sed -e "1,/loaded/d"

377.9967pt
```

Note I changed `\tt` to `\texttt` as `\tt` is not defined in the LaTeX format, if you use the string as given in the question the output is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\contnt ->\tt
```

(In classes where `\tt` is defined the usage is not as used in the MWE, the syntax is `{\tt text}` not `\tt{text}` but in the base LaTeX format it is not defined at all.)

Answer (score 3):

it is not clear to me what do you really want. However, here is a solution mit a savebox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\TBox
\newlength\TLength
\def\contnt#1{\savebox\TBox{#1}\setlength\TLength{\wd\TBox}}

\begin{document}

\contnt{\ttfamily I wish I knew how much space was occupied by this string when typeset \ldots}
The contents has a width of \the\TLength

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I understand it the OP wants to get the value in the command line without actual going over a document.